# Android CardsUI-Sample error Card cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: android

So i am trying to get a sample to work on eclipse but i am getting 59 errors. This sample requires the silk library which i have included but i still get errors.

https://github.com/afollestad/Cards-UI

The errors are as follows: http://pastebin.com/pghYPdsz

The import com.afollestad.cardsui cannot be resolved.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: `The import com.afollestad.cardsui cannot be resolved ` did you add this lib to your Java Build Path?

Comment: i checked and i can't find this lib at all. i added the silk library, but still am getting errors.

Answer (score 0):

go to project properties and change... target to :

target=Google Inc.:Glass Development Kit Sneak Peek:15